# Luci fails to start, openwrt_s905x3_k5.4.158_2021.11.12.1717

Tags: openwrt, lua

Fresh install of OpenWRT 21.02.1 on an X96 Air Android TV box. OpenWRT running on USB stick. Accessing the web interface gives a Bad Gateway error.

Running `/www/cgi-bin-luci` over ssh results in the following:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# /www/cgi-bin/luci
/usr/bin/lua: /www/cgi-bin/luci:4: attempt to index field 'dispatcher' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        /www/cgi-bin/luci:4: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

The luci script is simply:

```
root@OpenWrt:~# cat /www/cgi-bin/luci
#!/usr/bin/lua
require "luci.cacheloader"
require "luci.sgi.cgi"
luci.dispatcher.indexcache = "/tmp/luci-indexcache"
luci.sgi.cgi.run()
```

---

I've tried creating an empty directory `/tmp/luci-indexcache` with no difference to the result. Deleting it again also makes no difference.

I suspect there may be an issue with `luci.cacheloader`, but I don't know where to find it, or whether it is text or binary. I have *no* Lua experience. Googling doesn't return anything that looks like a solution.

Is anyone able to help me out please?

Comment: Which openwrt image did you use?

Comment: From github: openwrt-s905x3-k5-4-158-2021-11-12-1717

Comment: from openwrt github? I can't find that architecture in the *official* repo (which isn't on github - that's just a mirror)